# Using DFS to check if I can remove a specific "node"

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'm working on a tile based city builder. Currently the way the data is stored is an array of objects. Within each object, it has information like its `location` and other tile properties,

```
State.land = [
  { location: [0, 0] },
  { location: [0, 1] },
  { location: [1, 1] },
  { location: [1, 2] },
  { location: [-1, 0] },
]
```

The player can click on spots next to existing locations which would push a new object with the location into the land array.

Currently working on a delete method. You can only delete a land if all adjacent lands can reach `[0, 0]` ([0, 0] is not delete-able)

Im thinking this would be a good way to implement a nice path finding algorithm and DFS was the first that came into mind.

I've only ever implemented DFS while leetcoding but it's been awhile since I last done it. Would DFS be a good option for this problem?

Comment: Why not instead have an array of m by n tiles (max size), and each `tiles[x][y]` contain a `1` or `0` depending on whether that tile is traversable or not? That would make it much easier since you can directly access `x-1,+1` and `y-1,+1`.

Comment: If you want the map to infinitely grow, I think it will just be easier to do it this way and find a way to increase the maximum map size when you reach `x=m` or `y=n`.

Comment: Hmmm so youre saying to instead hand State.land be a 2 dimensional array? I dont think i see how that would help with this. Do you mind explaining a bit further?

Comment: Yeah, have `State.land` be a 2d array. That way, you can access any location you have in constant time if you know the coordinates. If you are at `x,y`, you can check for all the neighbouring cells easily by checking for `tiles[x+1][y]`, `tiles[x-1][y]` and so on. But, with the code in your question, to find each neighbouring cell, you will have to loop through the entire array and check for each `location` property in `N` time.